# How do I answer this vector analsisy question?

Tags: vector-analysis

Let v be a vector field on $R^2 \ (0, 0)$ of the form v(x, y) = f(r)(x, y), where $r =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and f : (0, ∞) → R is continuously differentiable.

Let $C_{R}$ be the circle of radius R centred at the origin. Evaluate the counterclockwise flux ¸ $$\oint_C v.n \,ds$$
in terms of f.

So far I have done:
$For (x, y) ∈ C_{R}, x2 + y^2 = R^2$ and n(x, y) = $\frac{1}{R}$
(x, y).  Therefore
$\oint_C v.n \,ds$$ = $$\oint_C \frac{f(R)}{R}(x,y).(x,y) \,ds$ = $2\pi Rf(R)$.

But the solution is $2\pi R^2f(R)$. Where did the other R come from?

Comment: From the polar coordinates Jacobian?

Answer (score 1):

$\oint_C \frac{f(R)}{R}(x,y).(x,y) \,ds$ is correct.
But $(x,y).(x,y)=R^2$ , not $R$ (see [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) ) ! 
So : $\oint_C \frac{f(R)}{R}(x,y).(x,y) \,ds=\oint_C Rf(R)  \,ds = Rf(R) \oint_C  \,ds = Rf(R) \cdot 2\pi R   =2\pi R^2f(R)$

PS : $\oint_C  \,ds $ is of course just the circumference of the circle : $2 \pi R$.